# Carrierwave downsampling PDFs when uploading to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave to upload files (carrierwave 0.6.2, Rails 3.2.3). In development files are saved locally, on production they're saved to S3 using Fog.

When a PDF is uploaded on production, it appears to be resampled by imagemagick and it's quality is reduced. Also, the file size increased substantially.

The site is hosted on Heroku, so image processing is done in the background using CarrierWave Backgrounder.

On the model I have various version calls, but all are triggered only if the uploaded file is an image:

```
version :thumb, :if => :image? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
end

def image?(new_file)
    new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
end
```

I've checked and it doesn't appear to be treating PDFs as images (the type is being detected as application/pdf).

When I inspect the files on my mac, it looks like the uploaded version (grabbed from S3) has been re-encoded by ImageMagic, suggesting that it isn't being treated as a non-image file.

Is there a way I can tell CarrierWave to avoid any image processing on PDFs?

Thanks in advance,
Phil.

Comment: Have you tried using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)'s `binding.pry` to see if your thumb version is being triggered for PDFs? If it isn't, your pdfs are getting processed somewhere else. And if it is, that breakpoint should hopefully give you an idea of how you got past the `image?` conditional.

Comment: Might seems an idiotic question, but did you removed the `process` call and the issue still happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself. It appears that a callback intended to correct image orientation and strip EXIF data was being called on all uploads, not just PDFs.